# Tweepy returns tweets on my mac but not on ubuntu AWS instance, instead it exits with no errors

Tags: tweepy

I am trying to use Tweepy to return a sample of Tweets. I successfully am able to receive and parse Tweets when I run the .py file on my Mac, however when running the same code in a Ubuntu instance on AWS EC2, the streaming connection is not kept open and the file closes.

I have tried to work out if Twitter is throwing any errors, however a try, except block does not throw any errors.

```py
class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print (status.text)

#Sets up our streaming listener
streaming_api = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(), timeout = 1000)

#Calls the streaming listener
def streaming():
    try:
        print ("Starting Streaming")
        streaming_api.sample()
        print("Still streaming")
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        print (sys.stderr, 'Encountered Exception:', e)
        time.sleep(600)
        streaming()

#Calls our streaming function
streaming()
```

On my mac it successfully prints the tweets and retains an active connection.

When I upload the file to the Ubuntu EC2 instance and run it it only returns:
"Starting Streaming"
"Still Streaming"
and then exits the program.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the date of the EC2 instance had drifted 20 minutes off the true time.

One can find the date of the Ubuntu instance by typing:
    date

One can update the time by typing:
sudo ntpdate time.nist.gov